# jooq generating invalid merge upsert on postgres

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I am migrating an application from postgres 12 and jooq 3.15.4 (professional) to postgres 16 and jooq 3.18.7 (professional). I have some queries using 'onDuplicateKeyUpdate()' causing problems on migration, since jooq now generate a 'merge into' query that does not execute on postgres. Before the migration it generated a 'insert into .. on conflict .. do update ..' that worked. I wonder what is going on here. Is the 'merge into' syntax supported at all on postgres?

Since I needed to ask this question I created a mock example of my problem. Ironically this mock example generate the 'insert into .. on conflict' query, that works.

```
        return DSL
            .insertInto(
                fruitTable,
                fruitTable.FRUIT_ID,
                fruitTable.NAME,
            )
            .values(
                mandate.mandateId,
                "Banana",
            )
            .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
            .set(fruitTable.NAME, "Apple")
```

Result:

```
insert into "public"."fruit" as "fr" ("fruit_id", "name") values ('2f8a4b65-7e1e-49d4-8530-ae2b6bb08857', 'Banana') on conflict ("fruit_id") do update set "name" = 'Apple';

-- is OK!
```

However my original example result in a 'merge into', that have a problem with the alias,

```
    return DSL
            .insertInto(
                mandateTable,
                mandateTable.MANDATE_ID,
                mandateTable.LAST_UPDATE,
                )
            .values(
                mandate.mandateId,
                LocalDateTime.now(zid),
            )
        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
        .set(mandateTable.LAST_UPDATE, LocalDateTime.now(zid))
```

```
-- Executing SQL:

merge into "public"."mandate" as "m" using (select '2f8a4b65-7e1e-49d4-8530-ae2b6bb08857', timestamp '2023-12-07 18:05:33.033756553') as "t" ("mandate_id", "last_update") on ("public"."mandate"."mandate_id" = "t"."mandate_id" or "public"."mandate"."portfolio_id" = null) when matched then update set "last_update" = timestamp '2023-12-07 18:05:33.033877463' when not matched then insert ("mandate_id", "last_update") values ("t"."mandate_id", "t"."last_update");

-- org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException:
-- SQL [merge into "public"."mandate" as "m" using (select '2f8a4b65-7e1e-49d4-8530-ae2b6bb08857', timestamp '2023-12-07 18:05:33.033756553') as "t" ("mandate_id", "last_update") on ("public"."mandate"."mandate_id" = "t"."mandate_id" or "public"."mandate"."portfolio_id" = null) when matched then update set "last_update" = timestamp '2023-12-07 18:05:33.033877463' when not matched then insert ("mandate_id", "last_update") values ("t"."mandate_id", "t"."last_update")]; Batch entry 1 merge into "public"."mandate" as "m" using (select '2f8a4b65-7e1e-49d4-8530-ae2b6bb08857', timestamp '2023-12-07 18:05:33.033756553') as "t" ("mandate_id", "last_update") on ("public"."mandate"."mandate_id" = "t"."mandate_id" or "public"."mandate"."portfolio_id" = null) when matched then update set "last_update" = timestamp '2023-12-07 18:05:33.033877463' when not matched then insert ("mandate_id", "last_update") values ("t"."mandate_id", "t"."last_update")
-- was aborted: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "mandate"
--  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "m".
```

If I remove the alias I get into the next problem,

```
    return DSL
            .insertInto(
                Tables.MANDATE,
                Tables.MANDATE.MANDATE_ID,
                Tables.MANDATE.LAST_UPDATE,
                )
            .values(
                Tables.MANDATE.mandateId,
                LocalDateTime.now(zid),
            )
        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
        .set(Tables.MANDATE.LAST_UPDATE, LocalDateTime.now(zid))
```

```
-- Executing SQL:

merge into "public"."mandate" using (select '39d98a7c-39f2-4898-840d-90df7b22884b', timestamp '2023-12-07 17:57:27.106425382') as "t" ("mandate_id", "last_update") on ("public"."mandate"."mandate_id" = "t"."mandate_id" or "public"."mandate"."portfolio_id" = null) when matched then update set "last_update" = timestamp '2023-12-07 17:57:27.106553633' when not matched then insert ("mandate_id", "last_update") values ("t"."mandate_id", "t"."last_update");

-- Result: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException:
-- SQL [merge into "public"."mandate" using (select '39d98a7c-39f2-4898-840d-90df7b22884b', timestamp '2023-12-07 17:57:27.106425382') as "t" ("mandate_id", "last_update") on ("public"."mandate"."mandate_id" = "t"."mandate_id" or "public"."mandate"."portfolio_id" = null) when matched then update set "last_update" = timestamp '2023-12-07 17:57:27.106553633' when not matched then insert ("mandate_id", "last_update") values ("t"."mandate_id", "t"."last_update")]; Batch entry 1 merge into "public"."mandate" using (select '39d98a7c-39f2-4898-840d-90df7b22884b', timestamp '2023-12-07 17:57:27.106425382') as "t" ("mandate_id", "last_update") on ("public"."mandate"."mandate_id" = "t"."mandate_id" or "public"."mandate"."portfolio_id" = null) when matched then update set "last_update" = timestamp '2023-12-07 17:57:27.106553633' when not matched then insert ("mandate_id", "last_update") values ("t"."mandate_id", "t"."last_update")
-- was aborted: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = text
--   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I figure that the resolution would require either forcing generating a 'insert into' in place of the merge. Alternatively making sure that the id field is read as a uuid by the db, since it is now read as a plain string?

Comment: `or "public"."mandate"."portfolio_id" = null` doesn't look very reassuring either. As to the uuid-as-string suspicion, it is a [pseudo-type `unknown`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html#DATATYPE-PSEUDO) at this stage. Even if it did reach the db as `text`, it would be easily coercible, so I'd say it's tolerable. [`Merge` was added fairly recently in 15.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/15.0/#id-1.11.6.10.5.5), I'm guessing that's why its jooq handling isn't fully developed.